# What numbers would I apply to the equation $y=y_o+v_ot+\frac 12at^2$ using this simulator?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, projectile, free-fall

Using a [Projectile Motion Simulutator](https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/html/projectile-motion/latest/projectile-motion_en.html) (selecting INTRO from the four choices), I set the height of the Cannon at $15 \ \text{m}$, Initial Speed = $8 \ \text{m/s}$, the bulls-eye at $13.9 \ \text{m}$.  Using the Equation $y = y_0 + v_0 t + \frac{1}{2}at^2$, would the $y_0 = 15$, $v_0 = 13.9$, $a = 8$?

*Other information*: There is no added air resistance, both the Velocity and Accelerator Vectors are checked for total.

P.S (I really enjoy Physics but I'm new at it and I am trying to get a handle on it. Please forgive me if my inquiries come across as elementary because I am a novice in this fine subject)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Y_0$ is $15$ (height of starting point above the ground), $v_0$ is the initial vertical velocity of zero.

So to find the time it takes to hit the ground do

$$0=15-\frac{10t^2}{2}$$

Where the $-10$ is for the acceleration due to gravity and can be put in as $-9.8$ if preferred.

Solving gives $t$ is $1.732$s.

The horizontal distance travelled is then $1.732 \times 8$, the $13.9$m

All the best with it.

Comment: Thank you for that Mr. Hunter. What does the 13.9 m represent? Also, the 8m/s does not get input into the equation as well?

Comment: @ יהודה the 13.9 comes out as the answer for the horizontal distance travelled, but doesn't go in your original equation.  The 8m/s get's put in after you've found $t$, into the steady (horizontal) speed equation distance = speed x time, hope that makes sense

Comment: Once again thank you Mr. Hunter. I was confused because when tried to make a graph it came out real janky and just plain ugly lol.  I'm not asking for you to give me the answer because I am truly trying to understand the subject matter but how will I graph the "$y = y_0 + v_0 t + \frac{1}{2}at^2$"?

Comment: Take the $x$ axis as the time axis and the $y$-axis as the $y$ axis. Then corresponding to each time $t$, plot the corresponding $y$ that you obtain by solving this equation. You should get a parabola.

Comment: @Mechanic Thank you and true indeed. I appreciate that Mr. Mechanic. I was a little shaky and confused because for the Vot I was thinking is it 0 or is the Vo =0 *t. Insecurities my man  lol